# Ubuntu 14.04 desktop

Tags: 14.04, gui, .desktop

Hi I am new to Ubuntu and I find difficult to search for a file from the desktop GUI

I want to organize the desktop by the file is created but I am seeing only one option of organizing by name only

I know how to search from the command line and from File folder\Desktop but

I want to organize in GUI desktop to faster access the file